# problem with rake task

Tags: ruby, rake

While running rake task with parameters i am getting this problem.

```
C:\projects\Test1>rake test_rake_task csv_header csv_column
(in C:/projects/CyncErp)
** Invoke annotate_models (first_time)
** Execute annotate_models
krunal get_model_names
model_name = csv_header
model_name = csv_column
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'csv_header'
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1728:in `[]'
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2050:in `invoke_task'
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exceptio
n_handling'
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exceptio
n_handling'
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
c:/ruby/bin/rake:19:in `load'
c:/ruby/bin/rake:19
```

Any Solution ?

Comment: usually you pass params to a rake task like COLUMNS=xxx or what not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out problem..

C:\projects\Test1>rake test_rake_task csv_header csv_column

This is trying to find out other rake task csv_header which i don't have it.

And it's trying to build csv_header so it's returning error.

rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'csv_header'

That was not the proper way to pass parameters with Rake task..

If we want pass multiple parameter that we can pass it this way.

C:\projects\Test1>rake test_rake_task MODEL_NAMES=csv_header,csv_column

Answer (score 2):

rake task parameters have to be formatted `name=value`, and it attempts to use single words as task names.